# Mastodon Nginx Proxy Pass issue it wont pass through to the LXC container

Tags: nginx, lxc, proxmox, mastodon

I have been trying to self host a sign user mastodon, i want to point out it works if i directly forward ports 80 and 443 to that IP, it can be accessed from outside  all great.

I have a bunch of other websites in a lxc continer about 10 websites on wordpress and the firewall 80 and 443 are pointed to this so typically i just add a proxy pass for the domain run certbot and alls good with the world.  I CANNOT LOOSE port 80 / 443 to this lxc

From what i can tell  its the nginx on the lxc with the mastodon instance as if i add a catch all default to the server the proxy pass loads no problems. Its only when its going to mastodons Nginx config i get the too many redirects issue.

I am at a bit of a loss on how to solve this as i never had this issue before....

Flow Map

domain > 80/443  > router  >  nginx proxy >   Mastodon lxc   =  Too many redirects

Nginx Config proxypass

```
server {
    server_name nameysitem.quest;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://10.255.192.84:80;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/nameysitem.quest/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/nameysitem.quest/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always; # managed by Certbot


    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/nameysitem.quest/chain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_stapling on; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_stapling_verify on; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = nameysitem.quest) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name nameysitem.quest;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://10.255.192.84:80;
    }

    listen 80; # managed by Certbot
```

The LXC Nginx Config for mastodon as i said it works if i change the ip to the lxc ip in the firewall

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default upgrade;
  ''      close;
}

upstream backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000 fail_timeout=0;
}

upstream streaming {
    server 127.0.0.1:4000 fail_timeout=0;
}

proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=CACHE:10m inactive=7d max_size=1g;

server {
    if ($host = nameysitem.quest) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name nameysitem.quest;
root /var/www/mastodon/public;

  location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ { allow all; }
  location / { return 301 https://$host$request_uri; }


}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name nameysitem.quest;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
  ssl_ciphers HIGH:!MEDIUM:!LOW:!aNULL:!NULL:!SHA;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_session_tickets off;

  # Uncomment these lines once you acquire a certificate:
  # ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  # ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/nameysitem.quest/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/nameysitem.quest/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot




  keepalive_timeout    70;
  sendfile             on;
  client_max_body_size 80m;
root /var/www/mastodon/public;

 gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_comp_level 6;
  gzip_buffers 16 8k;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript image/svg+xml >

  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;

  location / {
    try_files $uri @proxy;
  }

  location ~ ^/(emoji|packs|system/accounts/avatars|system/media_attachments/files) {
    add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=31536000, immutable";
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;
    try_files $uri @proxy;
  }

  location /sw.js {
    add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=0";
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;
    try_files $uri @proxy;
  }

location @proxy {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Proxy "";
    proxy_pass_header Server;

    proxy_pass http://backend;
    proxy_buffering on;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;

    proxy_cache CACHE;
    proxy_cache_valid 200 7d;
    proxy_cache_valid 410 24h;
    proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
    add_header X-Cached $upstream_cache_status;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;

    tcp_nodelay on;

  }

location /api/v1/streaming {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Proxy "";

    proxy_pass http://streaming;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;

    tcp_nodelay on;
  }

  error_page 500 501 502 503 504 /500.html;


    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/nameysitem.quest/chain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_stapling on; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_stapling_verify on; # managed by Certbot

}
```

I just dont know what to do now  its only this that doesnt work

i just get too many redirects

Comment: I just put a slightly tweaked mastodon [nginx config](https://github.com/mastodon/mastodon/blob/main/dist/nginx.conf) as a new site on the nginx proxy. I didn't run nginx inside lxc but set `RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=true` in `.env.production`. Also `lxc config device add mastodon tcp3000 proxy ...`, etc, to allow access to the ports

Answer (score 0):

```
proxy_pass http://backend;
```

If script is trying to check for SSL and see only "http", it tries to redirect to "https" and can loop itself. You should try:

```
proxy_pass https://backend;
```

But you will need to redirect all http traffic to https with nginx for security reasons.